# Preserving Tags in DocFX Conceptual Documentation

Tags: html, markdown, docfx

I want DocFx to preserve or escape tags such as `<` and `>` in the content of generated html files.

Currently, DocFx converts `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively in the generated html file content.

I am looking for a way to pass dynamic data to the html documentation by using php tags `<?php` so that I configure the web server to pass `.html` files in a directory to `PHP` processor.

However, when I include `<?php` in the documentation, the build creates in the content as `&lt;?php` which doesn't cause the PHP code to be executed.

Kindly help if there is a way to let DocFx escape certain tags in conceptual documentation or with **markdown**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you don't just want your tags to be preserved, but that you want your compiled site to actually include PHP source code that's preprocessed by the PHP framework to render the final HTML, correct? In other words, you don't want to rely (exclusively) on the DocFx engine to precompile the HTML. Yes?

Comment: Jeremy, you are correct. What I wanted to do was to include some dynamic links in some parts of the documentation. What I did was to write a small program in C# which  read all the generated .html files and search for some defined placeholders which it converts to the dynamic links. Do you know of any way around this?